# How to avoid warning: ogr2ogr: Warning 1: Several drivers matching gml extension. Using GML

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr

I run ogr2ogr to create a GML file from a Spatialite file.

```
$ ogr2ogr dump.gml spatialite.db
Warning 1: Several drivers matching gml extension. Using GML
```

It always produces this warning, which I would like to avoid since it shows up
in my error log. And yes, I would be happy to just use that GML driver (and possibly happy with using any of the other matching drivers too).

How can I avoid this warning?

I have looked for ways to simply specify the driver manually but that does not seem to be possible just by setting some command line parameter.